# rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am working through Michaels Hartls Ruby on Rails Tutorial. in Chapter 3 I set up R Spec and autotest as instructed. So far I have done everything that was instructed in the tutorial but I keep getting this error message.

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:31 # PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:43 # PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:57 # PagesController GET 'help' should have the right title'
```

My Gemfile Shows

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'heroku'

group :development do

 gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

group :production do
# gems specifically for Heroku go here  
   gem 'pg'
end
group :test do

gem 'rspec',  '2.9.0'
gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
gem "spork",  '0.9.0'

end
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
   gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
   gem 'execjs'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

My application.html.erb shows

```
  <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
        <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
        </head>
    <body>
        <%= yield %>
    </body>
</html>
```

My page_controller_spec.rb shows this

```
 require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
render_views
#home

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", 
                      :content => @base_title + " | Home")
     end

     it "should have a non-blank body" do
  get 'home'
  response.body.should_not =~ /<body>\s*<\/body>/
end
 end 
  #contact

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end 
      it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_selector("title",
                      :content => @base_title + " | Contact")
  end
  end
#about
  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
            response.should be_success
      end      
             it "should have the right title" do
      get 'about'
      response.should have_selector("title", 
                      :content =>  @base_title  + "  | About")
    end 
    end

    #help

  describe "GET 'help'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'help'
            response.should be_success
      end      
             it "should have the right title" do
      get 'help'
      response.should have_selector("title", 
                      :content => @base_title + "| Help")
    end 
    end  
  end
```

pages_helper.rb has

```
module PagesHelper


      # Return a title an a per-page basis
    def title
      base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
      if @title.nil?
        base_title
      else
        "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
      end
    end
    end
```

pages_controller.rb has

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
        @title = 'home'
     end

  def contact
    @title = 'contact'
  end

  def about
    @title = 'about'
  end

   def help
    @title = 'help'
  end


end
```

Everything shows good in the browsers. But I still get these errors when my test are run using rspec spec/..

Can someone help?

Comment: @base_title doesn't appear to be set anywhere in your spec

Comment: Where in the spec should I set it. my page_controller_spec.rb shows it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", 
                      :content => @base_title + " | Home")
     end
is this where it should be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `@base_title`. You could set it anywhere in the spec prior to your use of it, but since it's the same everywhere you could put it in a `before` block, ie

```
before(:each) do
  @base_title = ...
end
```

You could also use `let` (but then the specs need to use `base_title` rather than `@base_title`

Comment: I have added `before(:each) do
  @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
     end`  to the top of my pages_controller_spec.rb. I still get same errors showing.

Comment: Solved!! They problem was also in the `class PagesController < ApplicationController
  
  def home
    @title = "Home"
     end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end
  
  def about
    @title = "About"
  end
  
   def help
    @title = "Help"
  end
   
end
 ` I took out the singe quotes eg.. 'home' and replaced with "Home" There was also some spacing issues in the spec after @base_title + Thanks for the help